# What will happen if I repost my question with new information?

Tags: support, questions, reposts

I am considering reposting a question that has gone "stale" -- that is, it is no longer new and therefore not garnering any attention. It also has content that is no longer relevant: it was a jQuery question before and now it is a Regex question, and it should indicate this new category.

What will happen if I do?  Would I be banned for that? If not, is there a protocol to follow, to ensure it is not seen as a duplicate or otherwise unwanted?

Comment: Don't repost. Read [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Why don't you just edit the question to change the content in the way you are describing? That will also bump the question to the active list.

Comment: Oh...I didn't know that would bump it up in the active list -- thank you, that is helpful.

Comment: related: [How long to wait before re-posting the same question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167990)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming anyone notices it (which is rather likely) it will be closed as a duplicate of your previous post.  It's also very likely to get lots of downvotes and not to be answered as soon as people notice that it's a repost.

Having a noticeable percentage of your questions closed and/or downvoted contributes towards a question ban, so doing this repeatedly can easily get you banned from asking questions entirely.

See [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) for how to *properly* get attention to your existing question, instead of reposting.