# Revisiting a question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I recently asked a question about how to get something to work.  One person answered that my code was working correctly for him, including in Firefox which I am using.  However, the same exact code is not working for me.

Is there a way to pursue this discussion, to try to nail down why his is working and mine isn't?  I don't want to bug anyone, but I would like to revisit the question and see if I can rustle up an answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question you'd like to revisit?

Comment: If it didn't get deleted, it should be on your profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Related, I think. [Whats the preferred way to ask multiple questions about the same code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158572)

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to *[window.location.href not working when href is same page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736763/643383)*? You can click that link to get back to your question, and more generally you can find links to all your questions on our profile page (just click your name pretty much wherever it appears on the page, e.g. at the very top). You can leave a comment on any answer, so you could ask the person who answered for more information.

Comment: This was very helpful Caleb.  Strangely, the person who posted that my code was working fine for him is not showing on that page anymore.

Comment: The answer you're looking for was deleted by a moderator about an hour ago. It might have been flagged as not an answer, since it was more like a comment requesting information. If its important you might flag your question for moderator attention and ask to undefeated the answer.

Comment: The answer you're looking for is probably this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15737555. You won't be able to see it since it's deleted, but it may help if you're going to contact a moderator.